# Scripting a stored procedure database first including READONLY parameter

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

Why was the READONLY parameter not generated through a database-first EF migration?

I've got a stored procedure with the following signature:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PWz_P_GetshowOfferings]
    (@showID INT = NULL,
     @SegmentID INT = NULL,
     @SegmentKey VARCHAR(40) = NULL,
     @ChannelID INT,
     @ChannelKey VARCHAR(40) = NULL,
     @SalesRegionID INT,
     @ReturnExpiredOfferings BIT,
     @AccountID INT = NULL,
     @AccountFilterPairs PWz_TT_KeyValuePair READONLY)
```

The following was generated in the context:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<PWzPGetAvailableOfferingsResult> PWz_P_GetshowOfferings(Nullable<int> showID, Nullable<int> segmentID, Nullable<int> channelID, Nullable<int> salesRegionID, Nullable<bool> returnExpiredOfferings, Nullable<int> accountID)
{
    var showIDParameter = showID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("showID", showID) :
            new ObjectParameter("showID", typeof(int));

    var segmentIDParameter = segmentID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("SegmentID", segmentID) :
            new ObjectParameter("SegmentID", typeof(int));

    var channelIDParameter = channelID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("ChannelID", channelID) :
            new ObjectParameter("ChannelID", typeof(int));

    var salesRegionIDParameter = salesRegionID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("SalesRegionID", salesRegionID) :
            new ObjectParameter("SalesRegionID", typeof(int));

    var returnExpiredOfferingsParameter = returnExpiredOfferings.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("ReturnExpiredOfferings", returnExpiredOfferings) :
            new ObjectParameter("ReturnExpiredOfferings", typeof(bool));

    var accountIDParameter = accountID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("AccountID", accountID) :
            new ObjectParameter("AccountID", typeof(int));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<PWzPGetAvailableOfferingsResult>("PWz_P_GetshowOfferings", showIDParameter, segmentIDParameter, channelIDParameter, salesRegionIDParameter, returnExpiredOfferingsParameter, accountIDParameter);
}
```

Why was this parameter not generated in the context?

```
@AccountFilterPairs PWz_TT_KeyValuePair READONLY
```